# Signing into Ubuntu from macos - file sharing

Tags: networking, 18.04, file-sharing, macosx, lan

Does anyone have the steps to sign into Ubuntu from macos? I click "Connect As..." and I use my username and password, and it says it's wrong. Has anyone had any luck? I can use the Guest account, but I want to sign in to access all my files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you connecting to your Ubuntu machine? Samba? If so, check out this tutorial. 
https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-samba

It's pretty straightforward. An important thing to note is that the service doesn't use the system users/passwords as your system.